# How to query between hours on change day without day

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table

```
ID    NAME    STIME     ETIME
1     S-1     07:01:00  15:29:29
2     S-2     15:30:00  22:59:59
3     S-3     23:00:00  07:00:59
```

i need to get NAME when my input is time,

my query

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM TABLE
WHERE '08:00:00' BETWEEN STIME AND ETIME
```

it's work if normal condition,
but if its S-3 its be wrong

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM TABLE 
WHERE '04:00:00' BETWEEN STIME AND ETIME
```

i need to get S-3 row

how i can query that?
thank you

Comment: It look like can be solved by a simple `OR (etime < stime AND...)` condition. The problem is, You have cross-day value, so how to know if a time is in the range of your `STIME` and `ETIME`? I mean, if your time range is 3 days then every input time is correct in range, but we can not know if your time range is 1 day, 2 days or 3 days... only if we have these provided data.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach thank you, i just need input time is on S-1/S-2/S-3

Comment: Specificly, how if you know `'08:00:00' BETWEEN '07:01:00' AND '07:30:00'` is true or false? It depends. If `07:30:00` is same day with `07:01:00` then it's **false**. If `07:30:00` is time of day after day has time `07:01:00` then it's **true**

Comment: @PhamX.Bach yes thank you for your advice and answer, its alrd been on others function, but thank you for remind me

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
WHERE (STIME < ETIME AND '04:00:00' BETWEEN STIME AND ETIME) OR
      (STIME > ETIME AND '04:00:00' NOT BETWEEN ETIME AND STIME
      )
```

This takes the two possibilities into account.